# Why isn't jQuery.append working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the middle of creating a small script to 'help' me with my homework. It uses jQuery. The script (so far) is below:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
document.body.appendChild(s);
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"; // Include jQuery

var tmp_1 = document.embeds[0].GetVariable("q1answers"); // Read raw values
var answers_1 = tmp_1.split(","); // Explode into array
answers_1.splice(0,1); // Remove first element (always 0)

var tmp_2 = document.embeds[0].GetVariable("q2answers");
var answers_2 = tmp_2.split(",");
answers_2.splice(0,1);

answers_1.push("LINE_BREAK");
var answers = answers_1.concat(answers_2);

$("body").append("<div id='answers-wrap'></div>");
$("#answers-wrap").css("position", "fixed");
$("#answers-wrap").css("background", "none");
```

The problem arises when it gets to the 3rd-to-last line. Chrome console claims that `Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'append'`, however if I extract that line and put it into the console on its own, it works fine. I can use a different method to insert HTML, but I would like to know what isn't working with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using jQuery only in the last 3 rows? Maybe its an error with the $ variable which would mean jQuery was not correctly loaded

Comment: @Alex Turn it in an answer

Comment: @jantimon not if thats not the case at all :) thats why i am asking

Comment: If this is all in one script, then jQuery isn't loaded yet at the moment you are trying to use it.

Comment: $("body") doesn't need quotes.  Should be $(body)

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with jQuery because when I take that line out and execute it on the page (which has already had the code above run, so it has jQuery) it works fine.

Comment: @jpr that is completely wrong!!

Comment: @JPR: What does the **variable** `body` refer to in your opinion? Selectors are always strings. Maybe you meant `$(document.body)`. `$("body")` is certainly correct.

Comment: try using `document.write` when doing this but my guess is same as @Alex , afaik you are writing new script element to the DOM but JS won't load it before going through his current script. Hence the error with $ which is not yet loaded

Comment: +1 @Alex Also must add that you probably are not able to use `.append()` because you did not loaded already `jQuery`

Comment: It seems like `$` is referring to prototype.js or something similar.

Comment: The only library loaded is jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're adding the jQuery script dynamically, it's loaded asynchronously, so it's probably not loaded yet when you're trying to use it. Use an `onload` handler for the dynamic script block:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
document.body.appendChild(s);
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"; // Include jQuery
s.onload = function() {
    $("body").append("<div id='answers-wrap'></div>");
    $("#answers-wrap").css("position", "fixed");
    $("#answers-wrap").css("background", "none");
}
```

---

The error message you're getting also indicates that `$` exists (another library, maybe?) and is not returning a jQuery object, so you'll probably have to use jQuery in "noConflit" mode, and use `jQuery` or a user-defined alias instead of `$`.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but may you are running the script before the browser has finished rendering the DOM?

Try wrapping the code in

```
window.onload = function(){
   // ... your code here
};
```

in order to execute it onload.

**EDIT:** changed code to reflect the feedback below, of course one cannot use jQuery's `$` before jQuery is loaded, my fault.

Comment: You're right, I see... @bfavaretto's answer is probably the correct solution to this problem.

Comment: This one works whereas @bfavaretto's doesn't, although this surprises me somewhat.

Comment: I had to change `$(` to `document.onload` as I was trying to access jQuery before it had initialised.

Comment: @microbug It also surprises me that it work (and that my solution doesn't). In any case, if onload solves it, you should use `window.onload`, not `document.onload`.

Comment: @microbug @bfavaretto: thanks for the feedback, I have modified the code to use `window.onload`

Comment: @bfavaretto in the end yours did work. I don't know why it didn't at first though... Thanks!